# Unexpected identifier with Namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have a simple code that makes a div element go back and forth on a page. Everything works fine, but when I try to use namespace it doesn't work anymore and I get "Uncaught syntaxError : Unexpected identifier" about the number 0. Why is that? How would you use namespace here to make it work? I litteraly just started namespace and find it a bit confusing.

```
<script>

        var MyNameSpace = MyNameSpace|| {

        var x: 0;
        var y: 20;
        var direction = "droite";

        bouger: function () {

            if (direction == "droite") {
                x:x+1;
            }


            else if (direction =="gauche") {

                x: x-1;
            }

            document.getElementById("bouge").style.left: x + "px";
            document.getElementById("bouge").style.top: y + "px";


            if (x == 200) {
                direction = "gauche";
            }
                else if (x ==0) {
                    direction = "droite";
                }
            }

        setInterval(bouger, 5);

        };

        MyNameSpace.bouger();


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in your code. `var x:0`, `x: x-1` etc.

Apart from that, using the `||` operator we assign `MyNameSpace` an object literal if it doesn't exist yet. You are assigning it a code block within `{}`. Instead, you can change `x`, `y` and `direction` to the property of `MyNameSpace` and use the `this` keyword. And you can't call `setInterval(bouger, 5)` inside an object literal. So, you can use `setTimeout` inside the `bouger` function to repeat the function after 5 ms:

```js
var MyNameSpace = MyNameSpace || {

  x: 0,
  y: 20,
  direction: "droite",

  bouger: function() {

    if (this.direction == "droite") {
      this.x++;
    } else if (this.direction == "gauche") {
      this.x--;
    }
    
    document.getElementById("bouge").style.fontSize = this.x + "px";
    document.getElementById("bouge").style.top = this.y + "px";

    if (this.x == 200) {
      this.direction = "gauche";
    } else if (this.x == 0) {
      this.direction = "droite";
    }
    
    setTimeout(this.bouger.bind(this), 5);
  }

};

MyNameSpace.bouger();
```

```html
<div id="bouge">text</div>
```

(`style.left` wasn't working. So I'm using `fontSize`)

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyNameSpace = MyNameSpace|| {
    x: 0,
    y: 20,
    direction: "droite",
    bouger: function () {
        if (this.direction == "droite") {
            this.x = this.x + 1;
        } else if (this.direction == "gauche") {
            this.x =  this.x - 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("bouge").style.left = this.x + "px"; 
        document.getElementById("bouge").style.top = this.y + "px";
        if (this.x == 200) {
            this.direction = "gauche";
        } else if (this.x ==0) {
            this.direction = "droite";
        }
    }
}
setInterval(bouger, 5)
MyNameSpace.bouger();
```

I edited your code to reflect how the Namespace pattern is used. it is an object with properties, in your code there were still semicolons and "var", which makes the namespace not an object